# org-mode 's table export to html, how to set column width?

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

I use emacs org-mode write my documents, and export to html.

For a table, i want to set column width(percentage of width), for example as follow:

```
#+attr_html: :border 1 :rules all :frame border :width 100%
|----+-------------------------------------+-----------------|
| ID | BUG                                 | Result          |
|----+-------------------------------------+-----------------|
|  1 | jdkkskdjskdsdjsdljskdjfskfjksdjfksf | ok              |
|  2 | 823jjsljfdkjsdskkkkkuuffggg         | not bug         |
|  3 | aaaaahhaaaaa                        | can't reproduct |
|----+-------------------------------------+-----------------|
```

when export to html , i want to set the width percentage of the 3 tags(ID, BUG, Result)  to (2%, 80%, 18%).

how to get it work?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by inserting css in the header. (If you want to go more fancy you can also add a `CSS`-codeblock.)
By putting a class on the table and the css you can make sure that only that one table is affected by the css.

Here is your table as you wished (I also added some background color so it is clear that the styles are actually applied):

[image: a table with coloured columns that have the right width]

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">
#+HTML_HEAD: .styledtable col:nth-of-type(1) { width:  2%; background: orange; }
#+HTML_HEAD: .styledtable col:nth-of-type(2) { width: 80%; background: dodgerblue; }
#+HTML_HEAD: .styledtable col:nth-of-type(3) { width: 18%; background: hotpink; }
#+HTML_HEAD: </style>

#+ATTR_HTML: :class styledtable
#+attr_html: :border 1 :rules all :frame border :width 100%
|----+-------------------------------------+-----------------|
| ID | BUG                                 | Result          |
|----+-------------------------------------+-----------------|
|  1 | jdkkskdjskdsdjsdljskdjfskfjksdjfksf | ok              |
|  2 | 823jjsljfdkjsdskkkkkuuffggg         | not bug         |
|  3 | aaaaahhaaaaa                        | can't reproduct |
|----+-------------------------------------+-----------------|
```

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903845/how-can-i-add-class-attributes-to-table-headers-when-exporting-from-org-to-html) with a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64031783/4128131).