# how can I add class attributes to table headers when exporting from org to html?

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

I would like to specify the width of each column in tables that are exported from an emacs Org-mode file to html.

A specific way of achieving this would be to add a class attribute to each `th` tag in the generated html.  And then specify the column formatting by class in my css file.  See for example,

https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

How can I generate class attributes from emacs Org-mode?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to add attribute the the header directly, but one could use the `:nth-of-type(n)` selector to style them.

```
#+OPTIONS: num:nil toc:nil html-postamble:nil ^:nil

#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">
#+HTML_HEAD: .styledtable { width: 400px;}
#+HTML_HEAD: .styledtable col:nth-of-type(1) { width: 25%; background: yellow; }
#+HTML_HEAD: .styledtable col:nth-of-type(2) { width: 50%; background: magenta; }
#+HTML_HEAD: .styledtable col:nth-of-type(3) { width: 25%; background: cyan; }
#+HTML_HEAD: </style>

#+ATTR_HTML: :class styledtable
| column1 | column2     | column3             |
|---------+-------------+---------------------|
| small   | medium text | very very long text |
```